# Add new values to foreach loop from inside the loop

Tags: php

Is possible to add new values to the array that the foreach is working with? So it will run (n+x) where n is the number of elements of the array before the foreach starts and x is the number of elements that were added to the array.
Yes, I tested.. and looks like NO.. so I'd like to know if I can do something to this work.

```
foreach($pages_to_visit as $key => $source){
    global $products;
    $links = baixarSource($source);

    foreach($links as $link){
        global $products;
        global $pages_to_visit;

        if(preg_match("/somestore\.com/i", $link)){
                if(!in_array($link, $pages_to_visit)){
                        $pages_to_visit[] = $link;
                }else if(preg_match("/\/produto\//i", $link) && !in_array($link, $products)){
                        $products[] = $link;
                        echo $link."\n";
                }
        }
    }
    unset($pages_to_visit[$key]);
    sleep(0.2);
}
```

Comment: you could test it in less time than it took you to post

Comment: I did it... but turns out that NO.. So I would like to know if I can do something to do it..

Comment: @Mr.Birkoff: That's exactly why it's a good idea to include code in your question.

Comment: adding that information to the post would of helped. so what's the point of doing this? why not create a new array inside the loop?

Comment: Where's the code, huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already figured out, using `foreach()` it is not possible, however when you use `for()` the task becomes quite easy:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    //code
}
```

This is due to `count($array)` being (re)calculated before every iteration. You can also use a variable that you increment yourself (incrementing is a way easier task than counting an array)

```
$max = count($array);
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    //code
    //when push an element just do $max++;
}
```

Of course this will only work with numerical indices but that seems to be the case here.

Comment: thanks.. so it's not possible.. but in my case I have to do with while coz I'm doing like a queue

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the "runner" variable as a reference in the foreach code if you want to modify the array itself from within the foreach.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Example (will only count to 9):

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$makeArrayLonger = true;

foreach ($arr as $blubb)
{
    if ($makeArrayLonger)
    {
        $arr[] = 10;
        $makeArrayLonger = false;
    }

    echo $blubb;
}
```

Example2 (this time it will count to 10 using the additional element added from inside the foreach):

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$makeArrayLonger = true;

foreach ($arr as &$blubb)
{
    if ($makeArrayLonger)
    {
        $arr[] = 10;
        $makeArrayLonger = false;
    }

    echo $blubb;
}
```

Comment: Although what you say makes no sense (modifying array elements is something completely different than pushing new ones and setting the element as reference should have no influence on the array itself imho), this code seems to work..

Comment: Whether it works or not, it's a bit too magical for my taste.

Comment: That's one of the PHP quirks you simply have to accept.
Even though you add the by-reference marker to the "runner" this affects the original array as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question right... I think what you try to do doesn't make much sense at all any way.

```
echo $countBefore = count($data);
foreach ($data $as $value) {
    $data[] = 'Some new value';
}
echo $countAfter = count($data);
```

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, actually, if you think of the array as a list of stuff to do -- a job queue or message queue of sorts -- and would like one iteration through the array to handle all the jobs/messages, including any that get spawned by the stuff in the queue.

Comment: Well, this does not match what he describes.

Comment: Not exacly.. e.g. If $key ==1 I will add 5 new values to $data.. so the foreach loop will run more 5 times than was expected to do.. got it?

Comment: @Mr.Birkoff: I'd be very careful, if x>n is the typical case.  You're talking about a loop that may never finish, unless you add less stuff as time goes on.